# How to use a border and a padding while using display table-row

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I am trying to use create a table by using the `display:table` css attributes.

The table needs to have a border at the bottom and a padding inside every row, like:

```css
.row{
    display: table-row;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    padding: 20px 0;
}
```

I have read that i can get the border by using this

```css
.table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.row {
    border-bottom: solid #000 3px
}
```

I also know that i can get the padding by using

```css
.table {
    display:table;
    border-collapse:separate;
    border-spacing:5px;
}
.row {
    display:table-row;
}
```

I am now in the the dilemma that i can't use both at the same time.
The border only works when I am using `border-collapse: collapse;` while the padding only works when i am using `border-collapse:separate;`

Is there any solution or workaround to get both, the padding and the border at the same time?

**Edit**
Heres an example (border doesnt work):

```css
.table {
    display:table;
    border-collapse:seperate;
    border-spacing:15px;
}
.row {
    display:table-row;
    border-bottom:3px solid #000;
}
.cell{
    display:table-cell;
    background-color: #eee;
    padding:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
      some content
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      some content
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      some content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
      some content<br> in another row
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      some content
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      some content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
      some content
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      some content
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      some content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Here's also a jsfiddle in which you can try to change the `border-collapse`attribute](https://jsfiddle.net/0mnpcy01/)

**Edit 2**

Heres an picture of what I'm trying to achive:

[image: Example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer you are looking for isn't possible directly. But if you wish to manage it with some hacks or other ways, here is the solution.
I just did a demo, you can customize to your requirement.

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 15px;
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
}

.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.cell:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  margin-top: 6px;
  background: #000;
}

.cell:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 100%;
  width: 15px;
  height: 3px;
  margin-top: 6px;
  background: #000;
}


/*  Delete below code if you want border below last row as well*/

.row:last-child .cell:before,
.row:last-child .cell:after {
  content: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
      some content
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      some content
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      some content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
      some content<br> in another row
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      some content
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      some content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
      some content
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      some content
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      some content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

Like this?

```css
.table {
    display:table;
    border-collapse:separate;
    border-spacing:5px;
}
.row {
    display:table-row;
}
.cell{
    display:table-cell;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    background-color: #eee;
    padding:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
      some content
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      some content
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      some content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
      some content<br> in another row
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      some content
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      some content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
      some content
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      some content
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      some content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```